# See if key exists in a String Map

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I am currently using the Map functor to create a string map: `module StringMap = Map.Make(String)`.

I then am trying to insert a set of mappings of strings to a list of `'a` objects into the StringMap. to check if the key already exists, I am doing the following:

```
match StringMap.find_opt key my_map with
  | None -> StringMap.add key [child] my_map
  | Some l -> StringMap.add key (child::l) my_map
```

However, when I compile, I get an error saying the binding for `find_opt` has an unbound value, even though it is defined in the signature: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/map.html.

I have also tried using `StringMap.mem key my_map`, but get the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
     'a StringMap.t =
       (StringMap.Key.t, 'a, StringMap.Key.comparator_witness)
       Base__Map.t
```

I've looked around to see if there is a typing error or something but have been unable to find anything. Any ideas as to why I am getting either of these errors?

Comment: The error messages for `mem` don't look like they would come from the standard OCam library. Possibly you are using a different (fancier) library than the tutorial is expecting.

Comment: I am using version 4.06- I believe `find_opt` was added in version 4.05. I am using jbuilder to manage the compilation - could that be causing the issue?

Comment: I think you're using a library that has redefined some of the standard modules. It's worth checking out anyway.

Comment: I concur, you clearly are using `base`, which is not the normal standard library.

Answer (score 5):

According to the error message you're using Base (or Core) library, which are substitutions for the OCaml standard library and have the different interface. In particular, the `find` function in the `Map` interface already returns an option type, and thus there is no `find_opt` function.

Perhaps, you've used some example from the jbuilder tutorial that enables this library automatically.

You can either switch to the standard library or enable the compatibility with the vanilla OCaml standard library by opening the compatibility module `Caml`, e.g.,

```
open Caml

(* your code goes below *)
```