# Encounter unbound value error when using Ocaml StringMap.find_opt

Tags: ocaml

I tried to write a small ocaml program and encountered an unbound value error when I used StringMap.find_opt.

I am confused by this error since find_opt in is defined in https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Misc.StringMap.html

I found [See if key exists in a String Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241252/see-if-key-exists-in-a-string-map) and tried to use StringMap.find instead but clearly in my program StringMap.find is defined as val find : key -> 'a t -> 'a so it cannot return a value of type 'a option as desired.

The error looks like the following:

```
$ ocamlbuild test.native
+ /Users/KKK/.opam/default/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -o semant.cmo semant.ml
File "semant.ml", line 253, characters 19-37:
Error: Unbound value StringMap.find_opt
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 13 targets (11 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

and the relevant code looks like the following:

```
let f2 = function
              Some _ -> raise (Failure ("trying to redeclare variable"))
              | None ->
                let f3 = function
                  Array(t1, t2) ->
                    if (check_array_type (t1, t2)) then let lvs' = StringMap.add id t envs.lvs in let envs2 = {stmts = SVdecl(t, id, (Void, SNoexpr)) :: envs.stmts; lvs = lvs'} in envs2
                    else raise(Failure("array key must be int or string"))
                  | _ ->  let lvs' = StringMap.add id t envs.lvs in let envs2 = {stmts = SVdecl(t, id, (Void, SNoexpr)) :: envs.stmts; lvs = lvs'} in envs2
                in f3 t
            in f2 (StringMap.find_opt id envs.lvs)
```

Edit:
My Ocaml version is 4.07.1. and I already included

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
```

at the beginning of my file.
Edit2:
It turns out that my toplevel ocaml has version 4.02.3 and that caused the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show which version of the OCaml compiler you're working with? To do so, just edit your question with the output of `ocaml --version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, there is no actual `Misc` module. I've never heard of it, and it doesn't seem to appear in the actual text of the manual. The only link (that I can find) is from the index of modules. I'm thinking this might represent unintended leakage of some internal modules. (But I could be wrong.)

You can make your own StringMap module like this:

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
```

The `find_opt` function was introduced in OCaml 4.05.

Comment: I was able to find a `Misc` module in the `compiler-libs` package using `omod`: ```utop # Omod.load "Misc";;
[INC] /Users/sf/.opam/4.07.0/lib/ocaml
[INC] /Users/sf/.opam/4.07.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
- : bool = true```  But I can't load it in to the top level...

Comment: I indeed made my own StringMap module by using module StringMap = Map.Make(String) at the beginning of my file.

Comment: @PLNewbie My guess, then, (as per my comment to your question) is that you are using an older version of OCaml, prior to the documented introduction of this function.

Comment: @ShonFeder That's probably not the cause since my ocaml has version 4.07.1.

Comment: @ShonFede Actually, I think that is the problem. My toplevel ocaml has version 4.02.3 although my ocaml installed by homebrew has version 4.07.1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Looks like `ocamlbuild -which ocaml` will show which version it's building with. Can you confirm that this shows the older version?